# Create variable name with increment

Tags: javascript

I need to create dynamically name of variable with a loop .

example:

const1 = test;

const2 = test;

const3 = test;
....

I try this , but that only create 20 same variable name in array

I need a unique name increment by 1 at each loop and return each variable to use after.

```
function createVariables(){
  var accounts = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
      accounts[i] = "whatever";
  }

  return accounts;
}
```

how can I do this ?

Comment: The code you posted looks like a fine solution. Generally when you find yourself wanting to name variables with names like that, you really want an array. That's what arrays are for.

Comment: This sounds like a textbook [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what exactly do need this for?

Comment: Making that many variables really does not make any sense and is not easy maintainable. Using an array is a better approach. What is using the variables?

Comment: does the function trigger on a button click?

Answer (score 2):

Using Object could be the work around

```js
var accounts = {};

  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
      accounts["const"+i] = "test";
  }
  
  console.log(accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need variable (not array), then you can use this code:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
  window[`whatever${i}`] = + i; 
}

console.log(whatever0)
console.log(whatever1)
//...
console.log(whatever19)
```

See in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/thvc2ew8/4/

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you are trying to achieve? As mentioned in some of the comments, and array would be a better approach.

That said, one solution is to set values on a JavaScript object using string indexer (`['']`). See example below:

```js
function createVariables(obj){
  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
    obj[`const${i}`] = "whatever";
  }
}

// add it to a new object
const accounts = {};
createVariables(accounts);
console.log(accounts.const1, accounts.const2, accounts.const3);

// avoid adding it to global scope (like window)
createVariables(window);
console.log(const1, const2, const3);
```